# DKIM/SPF What does it mean when policy_evaluated fails but auth_results passes?

Tags: spam, spf, dkim, dmarc

I am trying to get the DKIM and SPF settings correct for a client who uses both GSuite and WordPress to send her emails.

I added this `dmarc: v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:l***@******ney.com; fo=1; adkim=r; aspf=r;`

(when I set the `p` to quarantine everything went to spam)

I added a google domain key `v=DKIM1`

And I added this spf that was supposed to be a catchall for google but doesn't seem to be working:

```
v=spf1 mx a include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

But the spf was still failing so I started adding ip addresses ... but it still fails.

Then this morning I got a report from google where the `policy_evaluated` failed for both DKIM and SPF ... but the `auth_results` PASSED for both.

I'm totally shooting in the dark here.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the <header_from> domain in the <identifiers> section match the domain for the <dkim> and / or <spf> domains in the <auth_results> section?
The <policy_evaluated> lists whether the tests passed *and* the domains are aligned with the header_from domain.

Comment: No the dkim is fw-mail.com and the spf is x.fw-mail.com.  What do I need to do?

Comment: The server / system sending the emails is not using your domain to prove it is authorized to send on behalf of your email domain (in the `FROM` header).
DKIM has a tag in its header `d=` which indicates for which domain it is signing. SPF domain is checked on the bounce / envelope address (Return-Path header). As long as neither of those is aligned with your `FROM` header domain, you will not pass DMARC.

Comment: Ok so ... I selected google for my DKIM because that's who is sending the emails ... but I'm also using aweber for bulk emails and an email responder from inside wordpress.  So how do I account for those differences?  I think this is what is causing the problem.

Comment: You need a DKIM public key published in DNS for each party sending on your behalf. Aweber has some documentation online how to configure a custom domain and the record you need to publish. I'm not sure about how to do that for you WP responder.
DKIM records look like: `v=DKIM1; p=[PlatformPubKey]` and optionally `k=rsa`, published at `selectorname._domainkey.yourdomain.com`